# Как зашифровать строку в C#

Tags: c#, шифрование

Использую следующие методы шифрования/дешифрования строки

```
/// <summary>
/// Метод для шифрования строки <paramref name="text"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Строка, которая должна быть зашифрована</param>
/// <returns>Этот статический метод возвращает зашифрованную строку <paramref name="text"/></returns>
public static string Encrypt (string text)
{
    byte[] byteText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    return Base64.Url.Encode(byteText);
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод для шифрования массива строк <paramref name="bytes"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bytes">Массив строк</param>
/// <returns>Этот статический метод возвращает зашифрованную строку из массива <paramref name="bytes"/></returns>
public static string EncryptBytes (byte[] bytes) => Base64.Url.Encode(bytes);

/// <summary>
/// Метод для дешифрования строки <paramref name="text"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Строка, которая должна быть дешифрована</param>
/// <returns>Этот статический метод возвращает дешифрованную строку <paramref name="text"/></returns>
public static string Decrypt (string text)
{
    string guidBase64Url = text.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').TrimEnd('=');
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64.Url.Decode(guidBase64Url));
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод для дешифрования в массив byte
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Строка, которая должна быть дешифрована</param>
/// <returns>Этот статический метод возвращает дешифрованный массива byte[]</returns>
public static byte[] DecryptBytes (string text)
{
    string guidBase64Url = text.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').TrimEnd('=');
    return Base64.Url.Decode(guidBase64Url);
}
```

Однако, многие строки при дешифровке выдают ошибки и/или некорректно дешифруются.

Есть ли другие более действенные методы? Желательно, чтобы шифрование строилось на строковом пароле, который ты можешь передавать дешифровщику. Что-то, например, такое:

```
public static string Encrypt (string text, string password) {...}
public static string Decrypt (string text) {...}
```

Код программы:

```
private const string MyKey = "123456";
...
var encryptedText = Encrypt("MyText", MyKey);
...
var decryptedText = Decrypt(encryptedText, MyKey); // MyText
```

Comment: То что у вас в коде, это не шифрование, а просто кодирование в Base64. Base64 это не шифр.

Comment: `Base64` - это не шифромавание, используйте любые существующие алгоритмы, например AES